# Is there an easy way to prevent particles from clipping into objects?

Tags: particles

I'm very new to particles and am still figuring out how to use them properly. This is something that came up multiple times and I wonder whether there is an easy way to prevent this from happening:

I have two objects adjacent to each other. As you can see in the picture, the particles of the underlying object are clipping through the above object.

How can I prevent this from happening?

My goal isn't necessarily photo-realism at this point, but rather to create somewhat believable concept models, so unless there's no way around this, we don't have to go all in on particle physics, collisions and so on.

[image]
[image]

TIA

Comment: What I've found, but is a huge pain to deal with, is converting the particles, then removing the parts I don't want (by boolean or by hand). A more elegant solution would be appreciated.